# Необходимо избавиться в предложении от склонения названия организации

Tags: склонение, падежи, лексическая-сочетаемость

Пример:
Инструкция Оператора (далее - Инструкция) определяет в Обществе с ограниченной ответственностью  (далее – Организация) обязанности..

Как в данном предложении без потери смысла, оставить в им.падеже Общество с ограниченной ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например:
Общество с ограниченной ответственностью (далее – наименование ООО) регламентирует деятельность (/ действия) Оператора посредством утвержденной инструкции (далее - Инструкция Оператора)…